# How to add preference to mutliple fields in elastic search query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, elasticsearch, mapping

I have the following data:
    makeStr: xerox
    modelStr: Designjet 1050C

I want it to match 
    xerox
    Designjet 1050C Plus Printer

but it is matching
    canon
    DesignJet 1050C

and currently I have this query

```
"query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": 
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": modelStr,
            "type": "most_fields",
            "fields": ['model.alphanum']
          }
        }
      ,
        "filter": [
          {
            "match": {
              "make.blur": makeStr
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "model.blur": modelStr
            }
          }
        ]
      }
},
    "functions": [{
      "field_value_factor": {
        "field": "isMpsSupported",
        "factor": 1,
        "missing": 0
      }
    }],
    "boost_mode": "sum"
  }
```

How do I give preference for makeStr such that it considers both makeStr and modelStr during search.

Answer (score 0):

More preference can be given by using boost. Refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

Something like makeStr^2 should work.